regular expression to find pattern in the same word
There is a string "123:987 767687:99 145:986 156:876 "
My regex expression is (\d{3}):\1
I expecting the result is 123:987, 145:986, 156:876
there is no result found. i dont undertsand. first group captured 3 digit. \1 means also 3 digits
why?

\1 means the first captured group, i.e. it means the pattern before and after : need to be the same, which is not the case for your input.

If you are repeating the same pattern several times, then use (?1) not \d. eg (\d{3}):(?1) but in your case, it is not hard to simply write \d{3}:\d{3}. Note that to ensure you have exactly 3 on both sides, use boundary ie \b\d{3}:\d{3}\b

@Onyambu, I believe Python's default regex engine does not support subroutines.

@CarySwoveland I did not check the language part. yes you are right re does not support recursions, but regex module does.

As @akuiper has mentioned, that \1 means, it will check what ever is before colon if same is after the colon.
I mean, your regex will be able to find "156:156" from the text but not "156:234".
To achieve what you want you should be using the regex expression as

pattern = r'\b\d{3}:\d{3}\b'

